# Trying to assign pictures to PictureBoxes in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a simple game, and first it needs to randomly load 16 PictureBoxes with images. I am not sure where the problem lies in this.

```
Public Class Form1

Private picArrows() As PictureBox = {pic11, pic12, pic13, pic14,
                                     pic21, pic22, pic23, pic24,
                                     pic31, pic32, pic33, pic34,
                                     pic41, pic42, pic43, pic44}

Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    'starts a new game

    'declares RNG 
    Dim randGen As New Random

    'uses RNG to determine arrow placement
    For intPicBox As Integer = 0 To 15
        Select Case randGen.Next(1, 5)
            Case 1
                picArrows(intPicBox).Image = My.Resources.Up
            Case 2
                picArrows(intPicBox).Image = My.Resources.Right
            Case 3
                picArrows(intPicBox).Image = My.Resources.Down
            Case 4
                picArrows(intPicBox).Image = My.Resources.Left
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

I get a NullReferenceException error on the line after Case X. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you didnt say what goes wrong or what the error is

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException error on the line after Case X

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: either you `picArrows()` or `picArrows(x)` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I get a NullReferenceException error on the line after Case X`

You cannot initialize your array like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private picArrows() As PictureBox = {pic11, pic12, pic13, pic14,
                                     pic21, pic22, pic23, pic24,
                                     pic31, pic32, pic33, pic34,
                                     pic41, pic42, pic43, pic44}
```

The Form has not been initialized yet, so it and all the controls on it have not been created yet.  As a result, all those control references are going to be `Nothing`, leaving you with an array full of `Nothing`s.  The result is a `NullReferenceException` because `Nothing` does not have an `Image` property.

You can *declare* the array there, but you can only *initialize* it after the form's constructor runs (`Sub New`).  Form Load is a good place:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private picArrows As PictureBox()        

        ' for best results you should use the same RNG over and over too:
        Private randGen As New Random()
         ...
        Private Sub Form_Load(....

            picArrows = New PictureBox() {pic11, pic12, pic13, pic14,
                                 pic21, pic22, pic23, pic24,
                                 pic31, pic32, pic33, pic34,
                                 pic41, pic42, pic43, pic44}
```

See also [NullReference Exception in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452)

Comment: Oh duh, now that I see it I realize how stupid that was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different arrangement without the companion array:

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    With New Random
        For col = 1 To 4
            For row = 1 To 4
                CType(Controls(String.Format("pic{0}{1}", col, row)), PictureBox).Image = {My.Resources.Up, My.Resources.Right, My.Resources.Down, My.Resources.Left}(.Next(0, 4))
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```